# Typing problem when making a parameter query in Firebase, with typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

I have a problem when using Firebase with typescript, where when trying to query a document in a collection by parameter, I receive the following typing error:

> Argument of type 'CollectionReference<DocumentData, DocumentData>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Query'.
> Type 'CollectionReference<DocumentData, DocumentData>' is missing the following properties from type 'Query': ref, isEqual, toJSONts(2345)

My code is below so you can help me, the error is specifically in the **findByParams** method:

```
import { injectable } from 'tsyringe';
import { firestore } from '@/firebase/firestore';
import { 
    CollectionReference, 
    DocumentData, 
    DocumentReference, 
    DocumentSnapshot, 
    Firestore, 
    QuerySnapshot, 
    WhereFilterOp, 
    addDoc, 
    doc, 
    getDoc, 
    getDocs, 
    setDoc, 
    where
} from 'firebase/firestore';
import { query } from 'firebase/database';

interface ISearchParams {
    param: string;
    operation: WhereFilterOp,
    value: unknown;
}

@injectable()
export class FirestoreService {
    private readonly db: Firestore = firestore;

    async createWithCustomId(collection: string, customId: string, data: unknown): Promise<void> {
        return await setDoc(doc(this.db, collection, customId), data);
    }

    async createWithRandomId(collection: CollectionReference, data: unknown): Promise<DocumentReference<unknown, DocumentData>> {
        return await addDoc(collection, data);
    }

    async findById(collection: string, documentId: string): Promise<DocumentSnapshot> {
        return await getDoc(doc(this.db, collection, documentId));
    }

    async findByParams(collection: CollectionReference, params: ISearchParams[]): Promise<QuerySnapshot<unknown, DocumentData>> {
        const wheres = params.map(w => where(w.param, w.operation, w.value));
        const q = query(collection, ...wheres);
        return await getDocs(q);
    }
}
```

I tried using other ways like the one below, but it didn't work, as I can't access the "query" or "where" method when instantiating a collection:

```
const userCollection = collection(db, "users");
userCollection.query(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've imported `query` from the wrong package:

```
import { query } from 'firebase/database';
```

`firebase/database` is only used with Firebase Realtime Database, which is a different product than Firestore.

You need to use the `query` from `firebase/firestore` instead.  Update your imports.

Comment: I tested it here in the code, that was it, you saved my day friend, thank you!